# Update only some values in a dataframe using another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to update certain values in one column of a dataframe with values from another dataframe:

```
# Main dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':['a2', 'a1', '?', '?', 'b2'], 'c':[100,101, 102, 103, 104]})

# Dataframe with new values for column 'b'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4], 'b':['b5', 'c5']})

# Result: Main dataframe with updated values for 'b', using column 'a' as index/key
pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5], 'b':['a2', 'a1', 'b5', 'c5', 'b2'], 'c':[100,101, 102, 103, 104]})
```

Comment: `df1 = df1.replace('?', np.nan); df1.set_index('a').combine_first(df2.set_index('a')).reset_index()`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris sorry, this just returns df1.

Comment: I forgot to replace the `?` with `np.nan`

Comment: @It_is_Chris worked! Thanks very much. If you care to post as answer, I can accept right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `?` with `numpy.nan` and then use pandas' [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html)

```
df1 = df1.replace('?', np.nan)
df1.set_index('a').combine_first(df2.set_index('a')).reset_index()
```